# Issue with numbers in SharePoint datasheet view for lists

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, excel-2010

When I'm seeing an *SharePoint (2010)* list in **datasheet** view, all numbers are padded with a zeros up to 14. As such 2 becomes `200.000.000.000.000`, so does 20.

I've tried repairing my office installation, but it doesn't help.

The same error occurs if I export the list to ***`Excel (2010)`*** via iqy query file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that had to do with Windows Language settings:

"Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats tab" and changing the format in the top dropdown accordingly fixed the problem.

I'm not sure if this has to be the same as your SharePoint or local office installation language settings, but playing around a bit fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to [list settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/create-change-or-delete-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-HA101782518.aspx) for your list  and change your problematic [column type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/create-change-or-delete-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-HA101782518.aspx) settings to [Number](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/site-column-types-and-options-HA010302196.aspx#_Toc277149824) and remove "Include decimal places" if enabled on your column.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, it doesn't solve the issue. Trying from a different computer, however, it does work - so I suppose it's an issue with my installation, though, I still have no idea of how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have content type enabled for this list?

If yes then disable that and try again..

Let me know the outcome

Thanks

Comment: It does not seem so, and it's nothing I myself have added. Though, I'm not sure exactly how to confirm this.